# ¿Como asignar multiples bone a un modelo en blender?

Tags: blender

El modelo 3d es simple, tengo un bone para cada brazo, y dos bone para cada pierna. El problema es cuando selecciono el modelo y luego los bone y hago ctrl+p no me sale "make parent to armature", sólo me sale "make parent to object". O sea sólo me está considerando el último bone y los demás como si fueran objetos.

Pd: debo mencionar los huesos están distribuidos de la siguiente manera:

armL-----armR-----legUpL  legLowL-----legUpR legLowR

Y pues sólo cuando selecciono el modelo y una de las piernas puedo asignarle el armature :/ uso blender 2.49

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ya lo solucioné, uní todos los huesos con ctrl+j ahora si puedo seleccionarlos como si fuera uno sólo. Por favor marca esta pregunta como resuelta